# Reusable jQuery select/option filter based on another select

Tags: jquery, html

Like the title suggests I'm trying to create a jQuery function to filter select options based on the the value of another select/option.

So far I have managed to create the function which works great for single use, but breaks when I try to use it more than once.

Here's what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<tr class='car-selection'>
<td class='label'>Car 1: </td>

<td>Manufacturer:
    <select class="manufacturer">
        <option>Select Manufacturer</option>
        <option class="audi" value="Audi">Audi</option>
        <option class="bmw" value="BMW">BMW</option>
        <option class="mercedes-benz" value="Mercedes-Benz">Mercedes-Benz</option>
    </select>
</td>



<td>Model:
    <select class="model">
        <option class="audi">Select Model</option>
        <option value="a1" class="audi">A1</option>
        <option value="a3" class="audi">A3</option>
        <option value="a4" class="audi">A4</option>
        <option value="a5" class="audi">A5</option>
        <option value="a6" class="audi">A6</option>

        <option class="bmw">Select Model</option>
        <option value="1series" class="bmw">1 Series</option>
        <option value="3series" class="bmw">3 Series</option>
        <option value="5series" class="bmw">5 Series</option>
        <option value="7series" class="bmw">7 Series</option>
        <option value="x5" class="bmw">X5</option>

        <option class="mercedes-benz">Select Model</option>
        <option value="aclass" class="mercedes-benz">A-Class</option>
        <option value="bclass" class="mercedes-benz">B-Class</option>
        <option value="cclass" class="mercedes-benz">C-Class</option>
        <option value="eclass" class="mercedes-benz">E-Class</option>
        <option value="mclass" class="mercedes-benz">M-Class</option>
    </select>
</td>        
</tr>


<tr class='car-selection'>
<td class='label'>Car 2: </td>

<td>Manufacturer:
    <select class="manufacturer">
        <option>Select Manufacturer</option>
        <option class="audi" value="Audi">Audi</option>
        <option class="bmw" value="BMW">BMW</option>
        <option class="mercedes-benz" value="Mercedes-Benz">Mercedes-Benz</option>
    </select>
</td>



<td>Model:
    <select class="model">
        <option class="audi">Select Model</option>
        <option value="a1" class="audi">A1</option>
        <option value="a3" class="audi">A3</option>
        <option value="a4" class="audi">A4</option>
        <option value="a5" class="audi">A5</option>
        <option value="a6" class="audi">A6</option>

        <option class="bmw">Select Model</option>
        <option value="1series" class="bmw">1 Series</option>
        <option value="3series" class="bmw">3 Series</option>
        <option value="5series" class="bmw">5 Series</option>
        <option value="7series" class="bmw">7 Series</option>
        <option value="x5" class="bmw">X5</option>

        <option class="mercedes-benz">Select Model</option>
        <option value="aclass" class="mercedes-benz">A-Class</option>
        <option value="bclass" class="mercedes-benz">B-Class</option>
        <option value="cclass" class="mercedes-benz">C-Class</option>
        <option value="eclass" class="mercedes-benz">E-Class</option>
        <option value="mclass" class="mercedes-benz">M-Class</option>
    </select>
</td>        
</tr>

</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var allOptions = $('.model option');    
    $('.manufacturer').change(function () {

        $('.model option').remove();
        var classN = $('.manufacturer option:selected').prop('class');
        var opts = allOptions.filter('.' + classN);
        $.each(opts, function (i, j) {
            $(j).appendTo('.model'); 
        });
    });

});
```

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rupfield23/SV4Q8/6/)**

I'd appreciate any help I can get on this!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Jquery:

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.model option').hide(); 
    $('.manufacturer').change(function () {
        var classN = $(this).find(' option:selected').prop('class');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.model option').hide();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.model option.'+classN).show();
    });
});`

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SV4Q8/10/

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this solution isn't cross-browser compatible... I've tried showing/hiding but using `display:none` on `option` elements doesn't work in most browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/SV4Q8/13/

I modified your html in following manner. I used `optgroup` instead of `option` . Also I used custom attributes and CSS which reduces the dependency on jquery. Please check if this is what you need.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class='car-selection'>
        <td class='label'>Car 1:</td>
        <td>Manufacturer:
            <select class="manufacturer">
                <option>Select Manufacturer</option>
                <option class="audi" value="Audi">Audi</option>
                <option class="bmw" value="BMW">BMW</option>
                <option class="mercedes-benz" value="Mercedes-Benz">Mercedes-Benz</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>Model:
            <select class="model">
                <optgroup class="audi" label="Select Model">
                    <option value="a1" class="audi">A1</option>
                    <option value="a3" class="audi">A3</option>
                    <option value="a4" class="audi">A4</option>
                    <option value="a5" class="audi">A5</option>
                    <option value="a6" class="audi">A6</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup class="bmw" label="Select Model">
                    <option value="1series" class="bmw">1 Series</option>
                    <option value="3series" class="bmw">3 Series</option>
                    <option value="5series" class="bmw">5 Series</option>
                    <option value="7series" class="bmw">7 Series</option>
                    <option value="x5" class="bmw">X5</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup class="mercedes-benz" label="Select Model">
                    <option value="aclass" class="mercedes-benz">A-Class</option>
                    <option value="bclass" class="mercedes-benz">B-Class</option>
                    <option value="cclass" class="mercedes-benz">C-Class</option>
                    <option value="eclass" class="mercedes-benz">E-Class</option>
                    <option value="mclass" class="mercedes-benz">M-Class</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='car-selection'>
        <td class='label'>Car 2:</td>
        <td>Manufacturer:
            <select class="manufacturer">
                <option>Select Manufacturer</option>
                <option class="audi" value="Audi">Audi</option>
                <option class="bmw" value="BMW">BMW</option>
                <option class="mercedes-benz" value="Mercedes-Benz">Mercedes-Benz</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>Model:
            <select class="model">
                <optgroup class="audi" label="Select Model">
                    <option value="a1" class="audi">A1</option>
                    <option value="a3" class="audi">A3</option>
                    <option value="a4" class="audi">A4</option>
                    <option value="a5" class="audi">A5</option>
                    <option value="a6" class="audi">A6</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup class="bmw" label="Select Model">
                    <option value="1series" class="bmw">1 Series</option>
                    <option value="3series" class="bmw">3 Series</option>
                    <option value="5series" class="bmw">5 Series</option>
                    <option value="7series" class="bmw">7 Series</option>
                    <option value="x5" class="bmw">X5</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup class="mercedes-benz" label="Select Model">
                    <option value="aclass" class="mercedes-benz">A-Class</option>
                    <option value="bclass" class="mercedes-benz">B-Class</option>
                    <option value="cclass" class="mercedes-benz">C-Class</option>
                    <option value="eclass" class="mercedes-benz">E-Class</option>
                    <option value="mclass" class="mercedes-benz">M-Class</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td.label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.model * {
    display:none;
}
select[data-class="audi"] .audi {
    display:block;
}
select[data-class="bmw"] .bmw {
    display:block;
}
select[data-class="mercedes-benz"] .mercedes-benz {
    display:block;
}
select[data-class="audi"] .audi {
    display:block;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.manufacturer').change(function () {
        var s = $(this);
        var val = s.val().toLowerCase();
        var nextSelect = s.parents('td:first').next('td:first').find('.model:first');
        nextSelect.attr('data-class', val);
        nextSelect.find('option.' + val).attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: Again not what I need... I need the car models to be filtered based on the manufacturer selected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML never change, below is best possible implementation

```
$('.manufacturer').change(function () {
    var modelObj = $(this).parent().next().children(".model");
    var selector = "option[class="+this.value.toLowerCase()+"]";
    modelObj.children(":not("+selector+")").hide();
    modelObj.children(selector).show();
});
```

Refer my **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/pzzEw/1/)**